# "The first time a continuous local martingale grows in absolute value beyond $n$" is a localizing sequence

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, stopping-times

How can it be shown that, for a [continuous local martingale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_martingale) $X$ defined w.r.t. the filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P; \mathcal{F})$, the stopping times $\tau_n := \inf \{t \geq 0 \mid: |X_t| \geq n\}$ ($n \in \{0, 1, 2, \dots\}$) are localising, i.e. for every $n$, the stopped process $X^{\tau_n}$ is a martingale?

Background: This claim is stated without proof in a textbook on stochastic processes ("Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie" by Jochen Wengenroth, de Gruyter 2008, in the definition of Itô integral on p. 179 and again in the proof of theorem 9.5.4 on p. 180).

Attempt at a solution: Letting $\sigma_n$ be a localizing sequence for $X$, $\sigma_n\wedge\tau_n$ is localising for $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $\tau_n$ as in your definition and let's look at the process $X^{\tau_n}$.

For all $n$ this is not only a local martingale (easy to this point) but a bounded one. The fact is that a bounded local martingale is a martingale follows from the fact that a local martingale is a martingale if and only it is of class (DL) (see [theorem 1](https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2009/12/24/local-martingales/)).

Being a local martingale of class (DL) means that for any family of stopping times  $\mathcal{T}$ bounded by a positive real number say $a$ we have that $(X^{\tau_n}_\rho)_{\rho\in\mathcal{T}}$ is uniformly integrable.

Now let's take such a family $\mathcal{T}$ and observe that $X^{\tau_n}_\rho$ is uniformly (i.e. for any $\rho$) bounded by $n$, as a  uniformly bounded family of random variables is uniformly integrable (*) we are done proving that $X^{\tau_n}$ is of class (DL).

We have shown that the stopped processes $X^{\tau_n}$ form a sequence of martingales and as $\tau_n$ increasingly tends to $ \infty$ almost surely, $\tau_n$ is an announcing sequence for $X$ which the claim we were looking for.

(*)a quick proof : see [the definition of U.I. on the planetmath webpage](http://planetmath.org/uniformlyintegrable), we have for any $\epsilon>0$ and $\rho\in \mathcal{T}$ :

$E[X^{\tau_n}_\rho.1[X_\rho>n]]=0<\epsilon$ meaning exactly that the family $(X_\rho)_{\rho\in \mathcal{T}}$ is U.I.

Comment: Thank you. But couldn't you have concluded your answer after the second paragraph? If a bounded local martingale is a martingale, then that's all there is to it, isn't it?

Comment: @Even Adad : You are right what follows is only the proof of that fact. Best regards.

Comment: Thanks. I've written an alternative proof, based on your answer.

Comment: @ Evan Aad : Regarding your proof (which is ok and much simpler than mine), I just wanted to say that I "tried" it but due to a confusion of mine I wasn't able to get to the result. The thing is, that I was conditioning on $X^{\tau_n}$ so the matter was more complex than conditioning  with respect to $\mathcal{F}_s$ (which is the right to see the problem). Best regards

Answer (score 1):

The following answer is based entirely on ideas suggested by TheBridge in his answer. The result is not proved in all the generality stipulated in the original post, but the restrictions are sufficient for my purposes.

***Lemma 1*** A bounded local martingale is a martingale.

***Proof*** Let $X = (X_t)_{t \in [0,\infty)}$ be a bounded local martingale w.r.t. the filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P; \mathcal{F})$. Let $\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \dots$ be a sequence of real-valued $\mathcal{F}$-stopping times that weakly increases to infinity, such that for each $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$ the stopped process $X^{\sigma_n}$ is a martingale w.r.t. said probability space. Then for every $t \in [0, \infty)$ $X_t = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} X^{\sigma_n}_t$ and $(X_t^{\sigma_n})_{n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}}$ are uniformly bounded. Hence, by the conditional dominated convergence theorem, given $s, t \in [0, \infty)$ with $s < t$,
$$
E(X_t | \mathcal{F}_s) = E(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} X^{\sigma_n}_t | \mathcal{F}_s) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} E(X^{\sigma_n}_t | \mathcal{F}_s) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} X^{\sigma_n}_s = X_s
$$
Q.E.D.

***Lemma 2*** If $X$ is a continuous local martingale w.r.t. the filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P; \mathcal{F})$, and if $\sigma$ is a real valued $\mathcal{F}$-stopping time, then $X^\sigma$ is a local martingale w.r.t. said probability space.

***Proof*** Let $\rho_1, \rho_2, \dots$ be a sequence of real-valued $\mathcal{F}$-stopping times that weakly increases to infinity and such that for each $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$ $X^{\rho_n}$ is a martingale w.r.t. the given probability space. Then, by the optional stopping theorem, $(X^{\rho_n})^\sigma$ is a martingale, for every $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$. But $(X^{\rho_n})^\sigma = X^{\rho_n \wedge \sigma} = (X^\sigma)^{\rho_n}$, and therefore $\rho_n$ is a localizing sequence for $X^\sigma$, Q.E.D.

***Theorem*** Letting $X$ and $\tau_1, \tau_2, \dots$ be as in the original question, *and assuming, furthermore, that $X_0=0\mathbb{1}_\Omega$ and that the $\tau_n$'s are real-valued*, then $(\tau_n)_{n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}}$ is a localizing sequence for $X$, i.e. it is weakly increasing to infinity and for every $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$ the stopped process $X^{\tau_n}$ is a martingale w.r.t. the given probability space.

***Proof*** The fact that the sequence $(\tau_n)_{n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}}$ weakly increases to infinity follows readily from its definition. The fact that this is a sequence of $\mathcal{F}$-stopping times results from the fact that $X$ is continuous, $I := (-\infty, n] \cup [n, \infty)$ is closed, and $\{|X_t| \geq n\} = \{X_t \in I\}$ (cf. the third example for a stopping time [here](http://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Stoppzeit&oldid=135600876), in German). Now let $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$. Then, by lemma 2, $X^{\tau_n}$ is a local martingale. But, by $\tau_n$'s definition, $X^{\tau_n}$ is bounded (specifically, since $X$ is continuous, $|X^{\tau_n}_t| \leq n$ for every $t \in [0, \infty)$). Hence, by lemma 1, $X^{\tau_n}$ is a martingale, Q.E.D.

Comment: Evan Aad: I was looking to prove the exact same thing as your question. I noticed that claiming that $X_{t \wedge \tau_n}$ is bounded seems not to be true. For example, if a path of $X$ starts outside the set ($\geq n$) then, it is clear that it will not be bounded by $n$. I might have missed something though.

Comment: @jpv: $X_{t\wedge\tau_n}$ is bounded by definition of $\tau_n$.

Comment: Evan Aad: Probably you have assumed that the $X_0=0$ a.s. otherwise this is not true as the example in my previous comment shows. I have also looked up the German reference. As I could not follow the language I could not completely understand the sentences there. However, I did notice that the author claims the result for $X_t - X_0$ and not $X_t$.

Comment: To expand on the example, if every path starts outside $(\geq n)$ then clearly, $\tau_n = 0$ and we have $X_{t \wedge \tau_n} = X_0$ which need not be bounded.

Comment: @jpv: You're right. I've added this restriction to the assumptions of my Theorem.