# If $M$ is a local martingale and $τ:=\inf\left\{t\ge0:\left|M_t\right|\ge\varepsilon\right\}$, then $M^τ$ is a martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stopping-times, local-martingales

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a filtration of $\mathcal A$
- $M$ be a continuous local $\mathcal F$-martingale on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with $M_0=0$

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Note that $$\tau:=\inf\left\{t\ge0:\left|M_t\right|\ge\varepsilon\right\}$$ is an $\mathcal F$-stopping time with $$\left|M^\tau\right|\le\varepsilon\;.\tag1$$

> How can we conclude that $M^\tau$ is an $\mathcal F$-martingale?

If $\tau$ would be bounded, then $M^\tau$ would be a local $\mathcal F$-martingale by the *optional stopping theorem* and hence be an $\mathcal F$-martingale by $(1)$. However, since $\tau$ isn't bounded, I don't know we can conclude.

Comment: The boundedness can't be relevant here, as the definition of martingale contains only fixed times.

Comment: For me this is basically the definition of the term "local martingale".  What is your definition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["The first time a continuous local martingale grows in absolute value beyond $n$" is a localizing sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1321177/the-first-time-a-continuous-local-martingale-grows-in-absolute-value-beyond-n)

Comment: @zhoraster What I've meant is the following: If $\sigma,\tau$ are stopping times, $\tau$ is bounded and $M$ is a martingale, then $M_{\sigma\wedge\tau}=\text E[M_\tau\mid\mathcal F_\sigma]$. This can be used to show that $M^\tau$ is a martingale. Now I would use this to proof that if $\tau$ is a bounded stopping time and $M$ is a local martingale, then $M^\tau$ is a local martingale. Indeed, if $(\sigma_n)_n$ is a localizing sequence, then $(M^\tau)^{\sigma_n}=(M^{\sigma_n})^\tau$ is a martingale by the former claim.

Comment: @NateEldredge $M$ is a local martingale iff there is a sequence $(\sigma_n)_n$ of increasing stopping times with $\sigma_n\to\infty$ such that $M^{\sigma_n}$ is a martingale for all $n$.

Comment: @NateEldredge The answer in the "possible duplicate" doesn't explain why $M^\tau$ is a martingale even when $\tau$ may be unbounded. The answer by Evan Aad just claims that this would be the case by the OST, but the OST cannot be applied unless $\tau$ is bounded.

Comment: Using the notation of Evan Aad, you apply the OST at $\sigma \wedge t$ to check the martingale condition. This a bounded stopping time regardless of the properties of $\sigma$

Answer (score 3):

Let $s < t$.  We have to show that $E[M_t^\tau \mid \mathcal{F}_s] = M_s^\tau$ almost surely.

For each $n$ we know, as you mentioned, that $(M^\tau)^{\sigma_n} = M^{\tau \wedge \sigma_n}$ is a martingale, where $\sigma_n$ is the localizing sequence of stopping times.  Thus $E[M^{\tau \wedge \sigma_n}_t \mid \mathcal{F}_s] = M^{\tau \wedge \sigma_n}_s$ a.s. (*)

(If you are worried about the boundedness of stopping times here, you can assume without loss of generality that each $\sigma_n$ is bounded, by replacing it with $\sigma_n \wedge n$.)

Now $M_s^{\tau \wedge \sigma_n} = M_{s \wedge \tau \wedge \sigma_n}$.  By assumption $\sigma_n \uparrow \infty$ a.s., so $M_s^{\tau \wedge \sigma_n} \to M_s^\tau$ almost surely.  The same holds with $t$ in place of $s$.  Moreover, $|M_s^{\tau \wedge \sigma_n}| \le \varepsilon$ a.s. for all $n$.

By the conditional dominated convergence theorem, with dominating function $\varepsilon$, we can conclude $E[M^{\tau \wedge \sigma_n}_t \mid \mathcal{F}_s] \to E[M^{\tau}_t \mid \mathcal{F}_s]$ a.s.  So we pass to the a.s. limit on both sides of (*) and get the result.

Note that this same argument shows the following version of the optional stopping theorem, which is really good to know:

> Let $M_t$ be a continuous martingale and $\tau$ a (not necessarily bounded!) stopping time.  Suppose that the process $M_{t \wedge \tau}$ is bounded, i.e. there is a constant $C$ such that $|M_{t \wedge \tau}| \le C$ a.s. for all $t$.  (You might say: "$M$ is bounded up to time $\tau$.")  Then $E[M_\tau] = E[M_0]$.

This is the version that Evan Aad was referring to in the question I linked in my comment.  More generally, it also holds if $\{M_{t \wedge \tau} : t \ge 0\}$ is uniformly integrable.  As a general principle for martingales, anything that's true for bounded stopping times $\tau$ will also be true if the *process* is bounded up to $\tau$.

Comment: 1. How do you conclude that $(M^\tau)^{\sigma_n}$ is a martingale? I guess the argument should be that $$(M^\tau)^{\sigma_n\:\wedge\:n}=(M^{\sigma_n})^{\tau\:\wedge\:n}\;.$$ 2. You're using the continuity of $M$ in your proof, but you don't assume continuity of the $M$ in your version of the OST. Did you forget to add this assumption?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: (1) $\sigma_n \wedge \tau \wedge n$ is a bounded stopping time, so as you know, $M^{\sigma_n \wedge \tau \wedge n}$ is a martingale.  (2) I do not think I am using the continuity of $M$ in my proof.  Note that the sequence $\tau \wedge \sigma_n$ not only converges a.s. to $\tau$, it is eventually constant.

Comment: (1) I'm sorry, but I still don't get it. First of all, if I got you right, $C$ is a constant (not an (integrable) random variable) and we even assume "$|M^\tau_t|\le C$ for all $t\ge0$ a.s." (which is stronger than "$|M^\tau_t|\le C$ a.s. for all $t\ge0$", unless $C$), right? (2) I guess you want to use that $(M^\tau)^n=M^{\tau\:\wedge\:n}$ is a martingale (noting that $\tau\wedge n$ is bounded) by the OST. However, the continuous-time version of the OST doesn't hold, unless $M$ (and the filtration $\mathcal F$!) is right-continuous (a.s.). But you don't want to assume (right-)continuity ...

Comment: (3) In order to shorten this, I would appreciate, if you could provide a proof of your statement, since I really want to understand why it holds. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Oh, good point, I didn't think about hypotheses of the OST.  This isn't a good time for me to study it carefully so I will just add the word "continuous".

Comment: Almost sure right-continuity of $M$ is enough, but you really need the right-continuity of $\mathcal F$ too. The latter is used to conclude $\text E[X_{\tau_n}\mid\mathcal F_{\sigma_m}]\xrightarrow{m\to\infty}\text E[X_{\tau_n}\mid\mathcal F_\sigma]$, where $\sigma_m\downarrow\sigma$, $\tau_n\downarrow\tau$.

Comment: Oh, and you didn't said anything to $(1)$. I guess we can do the following: Assume $M$ is a.s. right-continuous and $\mathcal F$ is right-continuous. Moreover, $$|M^τ_t|\le|X|\;\;\;\text{a.s. for all }t\ge0\tag2$$ (i.e. I don't think that $X$ must be a constant) for some $X∈ L^1(\text P)$. Then, $$M_t^{τ∧n}\xrightarrow{n→∞}M^τ_t\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0\;.\tag3$$ Let $t\ge0$ and $s∈[0,t]$. By assumption, $$|M_t^{τ∧n}|\le|X|\;\;\;\text{a.s. for all }n∈ℕ\tag4$$ and hence $$\text E[M_t^{τ∧n}\mid\mathcal F_s]\xrightarrow{n→∞}\text E[M_t^τ\mid\mathcal F_s]\;\;\;\text{a.s.}\tag5$$ by the DCT.

Comment: By the OST, $M^{τ∧n}$ is a martingale for all $n∈ℕ$ and hence $$\text E[M_t^{τ∧n}\mid\mathcal F_s]=M_s^{τ∧n}\xrightarrow{n→∞}M_s^τ\tag6$$ by $(3)$. What do you think?

Comment: Oh, and the argumentation should still work by localization for local martingales.